# Getting notifications of managed page using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications

Is there any way to get notifications of a managed page just as it can be done for users?

For a user I'd trivially trigger a GET request to /me/notifications. I've tried doing the same for a managed page (using the access token provided by /me/accounts), that is triggering a GET to //notifications?access_token= but I get a "Unsupported get request" error message, which I guess means that the notifications connection is not available for pages.

Is there any way to get this via Graph? The web page has a notifications link/shortcut for each managed page.

Comment: The message was edited... //notifications?access_token= should actually be: /pageId/notifications?access_token=pageToken

Answer (score 0):

Per the graph API Explorer, here are the connections you can access of the page, and unfortunately notifications is not currently on their list:

```
albums
events
feed
links
notes
photos
posts
questions
statuses
tagged
videos
```

However, you could try fql?q=

```
SELECT notification_id, sender_id, title_html, body_html, href
FROM notification
WHERE recipient_id=me()
```

---

**EDIT**

I used a valid PAGE access token and was able to get back data....

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "notification_id": "nnnnnnnnnnnn",
      "sender_id": nnnnnnnnn,
      "title_html": "<a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/nnnnnnnnnn\">xxxxxxx</a> posted on <a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxxxxx/nnnnnnnnn">Beer</a>'s <a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=nnnnnnn&amp;id=nnnnnnn\">timeline</a>.",
      "body_html": "",
      "href": "http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=nnnnnnn&id=nnnnnnnn"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How do you mean, didn't work?  You mean your recipient id was not found?  Your notification was not found? FQL error?

Comment: I got an error stating that access token could only be used with the Graph API, and not FQL

Comment: Strange. FQL is done via the Graph API.  So if it's a graph token, then you can query the FQL.

Comment: The exact error I get is "Impersonated access tokens can only be used with the Graph API", so I guess not all FQL queries are done via Graph API

Comment: Not directly, no, but apparently some pages notifications started appearing in the user's notifications list anyway: I don't know how that works and what are the requirements, though, as it seems to work more often for a page than another.

Comment: Odd, when I FQL the above statement using the graph I get back results and no error message.  Are you sure you're using a valid PAGE access token?  I've edited my response to show you an example of a notification.